# In Elixir/Phoenix, what is the correct/best way to iterate through an EctoEnum.Postgres for a select input?

Tags: enums, elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

We have the following enum:

```
defmodule PricingEngine.Pricing.ProductCategoryEnum do
  use EctoEnum.Postgres,
      type: :product_category,
      enums: [
        :shoes,
        :apparel,
        :accessories
      ]
end
```

In a form.html.eex template, we would like to make a selection corresponding to this enum.

Currently, we have the following code:

```
<%= label f, :product_category %>
<%= select f, :product_category, PricingEngine.Pricing.ProductCategoryEnum.__enums__ %>
<%= error_tag f, :product_category %>
```

This works, but `__enums__` suggests to me that this should be treated as a private property and not consumed in our code.

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rest of the team also decided __enums_ looks like it shouldn't be used.
Our couch suggested we should extract the list, like:

```
defmodule PricingEngine.Pricing.ProductCategoryEnum do
  @options [
        :shoes,
        :apparel,
        :accessories
      ]
  use EctoEnum.Postgres,
      type: :product_category,
      enums: @options

   def values, do: @options
end
```

Answer (score 3):

[`__enums__/0`](https://github.com/gjaldon/ecto_enum/blob/v1.3.2/lib/ecto_enum/postgres/use.ex#L53-L55) is a perfectly valid function; private functions are made real private with `defp` declaration instead of `def`.

This is a matter of the author thinking that way they look better.

Also, perfectly legit [`__info__/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/Module.html?#c:__info__/1) is named the same.